# create pydantic computed field with invalid syntax name

Tags: python, pydantic, pydantic-v2

I have to model a pydantic class from a JSON object which contains some invalid syntax keys.

As an example:

```py
example = {
    "$type": "Menu",
    "name": "lunch",
    "children": [
        {"$type": "Pasta", "title": "carbonara"},
        {"$type": "Meat", "is_vegetable": false},
    ]
}
```

My pydantic classes at the moment looks like:

```py
class Pasta(BaseModel):
    title: str

class Meat(BaseModel):
    is_vegetable: bool

class Menu(BaseModel):
    name: str
    children: list[Pasta | Meat]
```

Now, this work except for `$type` field. If the field was called "dollar_type", I would simply create the following `TranslationModel` base class and let `Pasta`, `Meat` and `Menu` inherit from `TranslationModel`:

```py
class TranslationModel(BaseModel):

    @computed_field
    def dollar_type(self) -> str:
        return self.__class__.__name__
```

so that by executing `Menu(**example).model_dump()` I get

```json
{
  'dollar_type': 'Menu', 
  'name': 'lunch', 
  'children': [
    {'dollar_type': 'Pasta', 'title': 'carbonara'}, 
    {'dollar_type': 'Meat', 'is_vegetable': False}
  ]
}
```

But sadly I have to strictly follow the original json structure, so I have to use `$type`.
I have tried using `alias` and `model_validator` by following the documentation but without success.

How could I solve this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This very much looks like you would rather apply a discriminated union pattern. See the following example:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import Literal, Annotated


example = {
    "$type": "Menu",
    "name": "lunch",
    "children": [
        {"$type": "Pasta", "title": "carbonara"},
        {"$type": "Meat", "is_vegetable": False},
    ]
}


class Pasta(BaseModel):
    type: Literal["Pasta"] = Field("Pasta", alias="$type")
    title: str

class Meat(BaseModel):
    type: Literal["Meat"] = Field("Meat", alias="$type")
    is_vegetable: bool


AnyDish = Annotated[Pasta | Meat, Field(discriminator="type")]

class Menu(BaseModel):
    name: str
    children: list[AnyDish]


menu = Menu.model_validate(example)
print(menu)

menu.model_dump(by_alias=True)
```

Which prints:

```
name='lunch' children=[Pasta(type='Pasta', title='carbonara'), Meat(type='Meat', is_vegetable=False)]
{'name': 'lunch', 'children': [{'$type': 'Pasta', 'title': 'carbonara'}, {'$type': 'Meat', 'is_vegetable': False}]}
```

This pattern has multiple advantages:

- It decouples the class name from the tag. This is usually preferred, because class names might change. But you might still want to read old files.
- The pattern is extensible and explicit. You can easily add new types of dishes later and just include them in the `AnyDish` type.

To reduce verbosity one can also introduce a short-cut like:

```py
class TypeLiteral:
    def __class_getitem__(cls, tag: str):
        return Annotated[Literal[tag], Field(default=tag, alias="$type")]


class Pasta(BaseModel):
    type: TypeLiteral["Pasta"]
    title: str

class Meat(BaseModel):
    type: TypeLiteral["Meat"]
    is_vegetable: bool
```

You can find more about discriminated unions in the pydantic docs: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/unions/#discriminated-unions

I hope this is useful!

Comment: thank you for your answer axel, I really would like to use distriminated union but by doing this I need to specify a literal as discriminator, so I cannot create the type attribute dynamically throught the computed_field. I really don't like to write the class name as an attribute, it's a repetition and could be misleading, don't you think?

Comment: I think it is not a good pattern to tie the tag for the discrimination to the class name.  Once you decide to refactor your code and rename classes, it will break all the serialization. Also it forces other code, that might read the files to use the same class names. I think it is much more common to define a separate discrimination tag. That's why the pattern exists in Pydantic.

Comment: I added a proposal to reduce the verbosity of the pattern in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your proposal, i ended up with it! I will mark it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

Obviously I wrote the question after more than 1 hour digging around this, and just after posting it I found a solution by myself:

```py
class TranslationModel(BaseModel):

    @computed_field(alias="$type")
    def dollar_type(self) -> str:
        return self.__class__.__name__

class Pasta(TranslationModel):
    title: str

class Meat(TranslationModel):
    is_vegetable: bool

class Menu(TranslationModel):
    name: str
    children: list[Pasta | Meat]
```

I already tried setting `alias="$type"` into `computed_field` decorator, what I was missing was calling `model_dump` with `by_alias=True`:

> Menu(**example).model_dump(by_alias=True)

> {'name': 'lunch', 'children': [{'title': 'carbonara', **'$type'**: 'Pasta'}, {'is_vegetable': False, **'$type'**: 'Meat'}], **'$type'**: 'Menu'}